# HttpClient provide not truly async operations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm confused about async IO operations. In [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) Stephen Cleary explains that we should not use `Task.Run(() => SomeIoMethod())` because truly async operations should use

> standard P/Invoke asynchronous I/O system in .NET

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

> However, avoid “fake asynchrony” in libraries. Fake asynchrony is when
>   a component has an async-ready API, but it’s implemented by just
>   wrapping the synchronous API within a thread pool thread. That is
>   counterproductive to scalability on ASP.NET. One prominent example of
>   fake asynchrony is Newtonsoft JSON.NET, an otherwise excellent
>   library. It’s best to not call the (fake) asynchronous versions for
>   serializing JSON; just call the synchronous versions instead. A
>   trickier example of fake asynchrony is the BCL file streams. When a
>   file stream is opened, it must be explicitly opened for asynchronous
>   access; otherwise, it will use fake asynchrony, synchronously blocking
>   a thread pool thread on the file reads and writes.

And he advises to use HttpClient but internaly it use `Task.Factory.StartNew()`
[image]

Does this mean that `HttpClient` provides not truly async operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean that HttpClient provides not truly async operations?

Sort of. `HttpClient` is in an unusual position, since it's primary implementation uses `HttpWebRequest`, which is only *partially* asynchronous.

In particular, the DNS lookup is synchronous, and I think maybe the proxy resolution, too. After that, it's all asynchronous. So, for *most* scenarios, the DNS is fast (usually cached) and there isn't a proxy, so it acts asynchronously. Unfortunately, there are enough scenarios (particularly from within corporate networks) where the synchronous operations can cause significant lag.

So, when the team was writing `HttpClient`, they had three options:

1. Fix `HttpWebRequest` (and friends) allowing for fully-asynchronous operations. Unfortunately, this would have broken a fair amount of code. Due to the way inheritance is used as extension points in these objects, adding asynchronous methods would be backwards-incompatible.
2. Write their own `HttpWebRequest` equivalent. Unfortunately, this would take a *lot* of work and they'd lose all the interoperability with existing `WebRequest`-related code.
3. Queue requests to the thread pool to avoid the worst-case scenario (blocking synchronous code on the UI thread). Unfortunately, this has the side effects of degrading scalability on ASP.NET, being dependent on a free thread pool thread, and incurring the worst-case scenario cost even for best-case scenarios.

In an *ideal* world (i.e., when we have infinite developer and tester time), I would prefer (2), but I understand why they chose (3).

On a side note, the code you posted shows a [dangerous use of `StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), which *has* actually [caused problems](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1190950/httpclient-methods-inherit-taskscheduler-current) due to its use of `TaskScheduler.Current`. This [has been fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/src/System/Net/Http/WinHttpHandler.cs#L553) in .NET Core - not sure when the fix will roll back into .NET Framework proper.

Comment: Thank you for the information, Stephen. Each time I think that I understand `async/await` property, here you comes and I understand that I know nothing.

Answer (score 0):

No, your assumptions are wrong.

1. [`StartNew` isn't equal to the `Run` method.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)
2. This code is from `HttpClientHandler`, not the `HttpClient`, and you didn't examine the `this.startRequest` code from this class. The code you're inspecting is a prepare method, which starts a task in new thread pool, and inside call actual code to start an http request.
3. HTTP-connection is created not on the .NET level of abstraction, and I'm sure that inside `startRequest` you'LL find some `P/Invoke` method, which will do actual work for:

   - DNS lookup
   - Socket connection
   - Sending the request
   - waiting for the answer
   - etc.
4. As you can see, all above are logic which really should be called in async manner, because it is outside the .NET framework, and some operation can be very time-consuming. This is exactly logic that should be called asynchroniously, and during the waiting for it .NET thread is being released in `ThreadPool` to process other tasks.